# Can't deserialize json from CMC

Tags: c#, json

I want deserialize json format from coinmarketcap for watching the prices.
the problem is, i get a error if i want the full ticker, and not only one coin. (the class is from json2csharp)

my question is, why is the class not working for the full ticker? hope anyone can help me :)

with "1" Coin it works -> https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/1"

with all Coins the Class not work -> https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/"

Class:

```
   public class USD
    {
        public double price { get; set; }
        public double volume_24h { get; set; }
        public double market_cap { get; set; }
        public double percent_change_1h { get; set; }
        public double percent_change_24h { get; set; }
        public double percent_change_7d { get; set; }
    }

   public class Quotes
    {
        public USD USD { get; set; }
    }

    public class Data
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string symbol { get; set; }
        public string website_slug { get; set; }
        public int rank { get; set; }
        public double circulating_supply { get; set; }
        public double total_supply { get; set; }
        public double max_supply { get; set; }
        public Quotes quotes { get; set; }
        public int last_updated { get; set; }
    }

    public class Metadata
    {
        public int timestamp { get; set; }
        public object error { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public Data data { get; set; }
        public Metadata metadata { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: property data in RootObject foreced convert to List<Data> ,
You should also delete all numbers that come before the object  and convert them into a matrix.
Otherwise it will be converted to unknown and homogeneous data. 
__invalid_type__.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the full ticker case you just need to parse the "data" element into a dictionary of string or int to Data object, e.g.

```
public class RootObjectFullTicker
{
    public IDictionary<String, Data> data { get; set; }
    public Metadata metadata { get; set; }
}
```

Note that you'll also need to make max_supply nullable in Data

```
    public double? max_supply { get; set; }
```

as e.g. Etherium has a null max_supply value.

Answer (score 1):

property data in RootObject foreced convert to List , You should also delete all numbers that come before the object and convert them into a matrix. Otherwise it will be converted to unknown and homogeneous data. invalid_type.

JSON :

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Bitcoin",
      "symbol": "BTC",
      "website_slug": "bitcoin",
      "rank": 1,
      "circulating_supply": 17140637.0,
      "total_supply": 17140637.0,
      "max_supply": 21000000.0,
      "quotes": {
        "USD": {
          "price": 6740.85,
          "volume_24h": 3714600000.0,
          "market_cap": 115542462921.0,
          "percent_change_1h": -0.51,
          "percent_change_24h": -0.41,
          "percent_change_7d": 1.88
        }
      },
      "last_updated": 1531181660
    },
    {
      "id": 1027,
      "name": "Ethereum",
      "symbol": "ETH",
      "website_slug": "ethereum",
      "rank": 2,
      "circulating_supply": 100591615.0,
      "total_supply": 100591615.0,
      "max_supply": null,
      "quotes": {
        "USD": {
          "price": 474.802,
          "volume_24h": 1542270000.0,
          "market_cap": 47761099792.0,
          "percent_change_1h": -1.25,
          "percent_change_24h": -3.07,
          "percent_change_7d": -0.16
        }
      },
      "last_updated": 1531181673
    }
  ],  
    "metadata": {
        "timestamp": 1531181347, 
        "num_cryptocurrencies": 1619, 
        "error": null
    }
}
```

generate c# classes from json

```
public class USD
{
    public double price { get; set; }
    public double volume_24h { get; set; }
    public double market_cap { get; set; }
    public double percent_change_1h { get; set; }
    public double percent_change_24h { get; set; }
    public double percent_change_7d { get; set; }
}

public class Quotes
{
    public USD USD { get; set; }
}

public class Datum
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string symbol { get; set; }
    public string website_slug { get; set; }
    public int rank { get; set; }
    public double circulating_supply { get; set; }
    public double total_supply { get; set; }
    public double? max_supply { get; set; }
    public Quotes quotes { get; set; }
    public int last_updated { get; set; }
}

public class Metadata
{
    public int timestamp { get; set; }
    public int num_cryptocurrencies { get; set; }
    public object error { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
    public Metadata metadata { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is too very helpfully :)